# On click only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if someone could help me with a function.

The onlick only fires once.

```
launchTagManager: function(id) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']'));
    document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']').value="change";

    $('body').append('<div id="tagManagerPopup" class="eesTooltip tooltipSouth" style="display:block;width:450px; left: 50%; top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);position: fixed;"> <div class="tooltipTitle">Add a tag...</div><div class="tooltipContent"> <div class="tooltipMessage"> <div id="ees_infoBoxColumn"> <div id="ees_infoBox"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner1"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner2"> <div id="ees_assetInfo"> <div class="row container" id="geocoder" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <input id="cu-geocoder-place" class="inputText" type="text" value="" style="width:290px;"> <a href="#" id="cu-geocoder-submit" class="guiButton light alignRight">Search</a> </div><div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:5px;"> <a id="addTag" href="" class="guiButton default alignLeft"><span>Add tag</span></a> <a id="closeTagManager" href="" class="guiButton light alignRight"><span>Cancel</span></a> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '#closeTagManager', function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#tagManagerPopup').hide();
    });
  }
```

`launchTagManager`gets called by an onClick of a dynamically added button.

The popup will close the first time I click the `#closeTagManager` button, but when I open the pop up the second time and try to close it stays open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: you have duplicate IDs. It's closing the wrong popup.

Comment: Can you give the button a semantic class?  eg `<a id="closeTagManager" class="closeTagManager" ..` and then use that instead of the id: `$(document).on('click', '.closeTagManager', ...`

Comment: Any reason why the click is being binded inside the function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this block

```
$(document).on('click', '#closeTagManager', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#tagManagerPopup').hide();
});
```

outside the `launchTagManager` method, and change the id's to a class.

like this:

```
launchTagManager: function(id) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']'));
    document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']').value="change";
    $('body').append('<div class="tagManagerPopup eesTooltip tooltipSouth" style="display:block;width:450px; left: 50%; top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);position: fixed;"> <div class="tooltipTitle">Add a tag...</div><div class="tooltipContent"> <div class="tooltipMessage"> <div id="ees_infoBoxColumn"> <div id="ees_infoBox"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner1"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner2"> <div id="ees_assetInfo"> <div class="row container" id="geocoder" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <input id="cu-geocoder-place" class="inputText" type="text" value="" style="width:290px;"> <a href="#" id="cu-geocoder-submit" class="guiButton light alignRight">Search</a> </div><div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:5px;"> <a id="addTag" href="" class="guiButton default alignLeft"><span>Add tag</span></a> <a href="" class="closeTagManager guiButton light alignRight"><span>Cancel</span></a> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
},
init: function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.closeTagManager', function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.tagManagerPopup').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the way you've tried to do it.  Firstly, you're hiding the dialog and then adding another one with the same ID.  jQuery will only find the first one, so when you open the dialog for the 2nd time and then click the close button, it will find the one which is already hidden.  That's why it doesn't hide any further dialogs.  To resolve that you can simply remove it.

Also, you're binding the click event handler inside the function that creates the dialog.  You only need to create that event handler once so just create it outside the function...

```
launchTagManager: function(id) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']'));
    document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']').value="change";

    $('body').append('<div id="tagManagerPopup" class="eesTooltip tooltipSouth" style="display:block;width:450px; left: 50%; top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);position: fixed;"> <div class="tooltipTitle">Add a tag...</div><div class="tooltipContent"> <div class="tooltipMessage"> <div id="ees_infoBoxColumn"> <div id="ees_infoBox"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner1"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner2"> <div id="ees_assetInfo"> <div class="row container" id="geocoder" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <input id="cu-geocoder-place" class="inputText" type="text" value="" style="width:290px;"> <a href="#" id="cu-geocoder-submit" class="guiButton light alignRight">Search</a> </div><div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:5px;"> <a id="addTag" href="" class="guiButton default alignLeft"><span>Add tag</span></a> <a id="closeTagManager" href="" class="guiButton light alignRight"><span>Cancel</span></a> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
}

$(document).on('click', '#closeTagManager', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tagManagerPopup').remove();
});
```

Alternatively you can leave the event handler inside the function that creates the dialog, since it's being assigned to a new button that is going to be destroyed...

```
launchTagManager: function(id) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']'));
    document.getElementById('metadata_field_multiple_text_701889_options['+id+']').value="change";

    $('body').append('<div id="tagManagerPopup" class="eesTooltip tooltipSouth" style="display:block;width:450px; left: 50%; top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);position: fixed;"> <div class="tooltipTitle">Add a tag...</div><div class="tooltipContent"> <div class="tooltipMessage"> <div id="ees_infoBoxColumn"> <div id="ees_infoBox"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner1"> <div id="ees_infoBoxInner2"> <div id="ees_assetInfo"> <div class="row container" id="geocoder" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <input id="cu-geocoder-place" class="inputText" type="text" value="" style="width:290px;"> <a href="#" id="cu-geocoder-submit" class="guiButton light alignRight">Search</a> </div><div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:5px;"> <a id="addTag" href="" class="guiButton default alignLeft"><span>Add tag</span></a> <a id="closeTagManager" href="" class="guiButton light alignRight"><span>Cancel</span></a> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');

    $('#closeTagManager').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tagManagerPopup').remove();
    });
}
```

If you do it the 2nd way there's no need to bind the click handler to the document.